# How to install grub when / is encrypted (luks) and /boot is not encrypted

Tags: linux, boot, encryption, grub, uefi

I have the following partitioning:

```
   |------+-------------+-----------+------+-------+----------------|
   | Name | Mount point | Flag      | Size | FS    | Comment        |
   |------+-------------+-----------+------+-------+----------------|
   | sda1 | /boot/efi   | esp, boot | 300M | FAT32 |                |
   | sda2 | /boot       |           | 2G   | EXT4  |                |
   | sda3 | /           |           |      | LUKS  | Encrypted Arch |
   | sda4 | /           |           |      | EXT4  | Clear Arch     |
   |------+-------------+-----------+------+-------+----------------|
```

I would like to be able to choose between an encrypted Arch and a clear Arch at boot.

- Encrypted Arch's `/boot` is on sda2
- Clear Arch's `/boot` is on sda4

It is the first time I try to repair grub. I read that I should use `grub-install`, but I cannot find tutorials that would apply to my specific partitioning.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system

Comment: I don't see the scenario where `/boot` is not encrypted in this tutorial.

Comment: Look again: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Encrypted_boot_partition_(GRUB)